# Calculating the number of like records in an unbound text box on a form. in MS Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an unbound text box **[txt_AmendmentOF]** on a form to count the total number of Amendments a specific record has in the database. So the user knows which amendment they are on. Just a simple you are on Amendment 3 out of 8. i have this calculation i am using in the Control Source field of the text box **[txt_AmendmentOF]**:

```
=IIf(IsNull([txt_Amendment]),0,Count([MIPR_Number]))
```

there is a Field on my table called **[Amendment]** its text box on the form is called **[txt_Amendment]**. I have the calculation return a zero in **[txt_AmendmentOF]** if **[txt_Amendment]** is null. I need it to count the record number **[MIPR_Number]** that are the same and return the total number of Amendments count in the **[txt_AmendmentOF]** text box. on my table i have private key field called **[ID]** it is an autonumber format. The problem with the code above is it is counting all the fields that have a **[MIPR_Number]** and returning the total row count of that. i am not an expert here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update to post..
I have also tried this and got an error in the text box

```
=IIf(IsNull([txt_Amendment]),0,Count([MIPR_Number]=[txt_MIPR_Number]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting by a condition is one of the basic dataabase tasks. To get answers from a db, you have to query the database (and that is done by createing a query).

To count same`[MIPR_Number]`you have to group the data (a group contains same numbers), then count.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id) as CountOfSameNr, [MIPR_Number] FROM Table GROUP BY [MIPR_Number]
```

Store this query as e.g CountMIPRNumber.

Now you have two options:

Use a Dlookup to get one value

```vb
=IIf(IsNull([txt_Amendment]),0,Dlookup("CountOfSameNr","CountMIPRNumber","[MIPR_Number] = " & [MIPR_Number]))
```

or add the query to form recordsource (join on [MIPR_Number], "SELECT * FROM TABLE" is forms query)

```sql
SELECT CountMIPRNumber.CountOfSameNr, TABLE.* FROM TABLE LEFT JOIN CountMIPRNumber ON TABLE.[MIPR_Number] = CountMIPRNumber.[MIPR_Number]
```

and reference the count field

```vb
=IIf(IsNull([txt_Amendment]),0,[CountOfSameNr])
```

Comment: So i created the query you provided the info above for. im also taking your suggestion for using the DLookup to get the value. In my text box it is returning **#Error** any suggestions? by the way thank you for your help with this matter.

Comment: i placed the **[iif]** statement as the text boxes Control Source.

Comment: [How to debug](http://cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx). Test Dlookup `Debug.Print Dlookup("CountOfSameNr","CountMIPRNumber","[MIPR_Number] = 1" )`, If change 1 to any valid [MIPR_Number] and show your querys sql (edit question)

Comment: lol Thank you after debuging i noticed it was a error on my part. Correcting the spelling small mistake and not it is resolved. thank you so much.